# How to hide the dialer intent while the call still active

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I've the below code that launch the `Dialer` intent, and make a call with the given number.

I need to minimize/hide this activity, so I'm making a delay of 15 seconds that call the `Press home intent` but t is not working.
How can I hide the dialer while it still active (i.e. still making the required call)!

```
if (isChecked) {
    val dial = "tel:12345678"
    val phoneIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(dial))

    val startMain = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).apply {
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    }

    val r = java.lang.Runnable {
            context.startActivity(startMain)
        }

    context.startActivity(phoneIntent)
    val h = Handler()
    h.postDelayed(r, 15000) // will be delayed for 15 seconds
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it using the below code, but not clear wha is the different between this and the above one in the question:

```
Thread().run {
    context.startActivity(phoneIntent)
    Thread.sleep(2000)
    context.startActivity(startMain)
}
```

Comment: A thread is not bound to lifecycle like View's handlers. The used handler may have been canceled before the task actually happen.

Comment: Thanks @LionelBriand any ida why even this is not working in `Broadcast receiver`?

Comment: An Activity Intent launch from a broadcast receiver need the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag to be opened properly.

Comment: @LionelBriand how can I do that! other than he code in question body?